Check whether the statement is true or false for diagonal matrices.
Check whether the statement is true or false.
Let $||.||:\mathbb C^{n,n}\to \mathbb R$ be a consistent matrix norm. Let $\Lambda=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n)$ be a diagonal matrix. Then,
$||\Lambda||=\max_i|\lambda_i|, \forall $ consistent norms.
My attempt:-
I know this result is true for $||.||_{\infty| \text{ norms}. || \Lambda||_{\infty}=\max_i \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|=\max_i |\mabda_i|$
For an induced matrix norm,
$$||\Lambda||=\max_{||\vec{x}||=1} \frac{||A\vec x||}{||\vec x||} =\max_{||\vec{x}||=1} \frac{||\Lambda \vec x||}{||\vec x||}=\max_{||\vec{x}||=1} \frac{||(\lambda_1x_1,\lambda_2 x_2,..., \lambda_n x_n)||}{||(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)||}=\max_{||\vec{x}||=1} \frac{\max_i|\lambda_i|||(\frac{\lambda_1}{\max_i|\lambda_i|}x_1,\frac{\lambda_2}{\max_i|\lambda_i|} x_2,..., \frac{\lambda_n}{\max_i|\lambda_i|} x_n)||}{||(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)||}$$
$$=\max_i|\lambda_i|\max_{||\vec{x}||=1} \frac{||(\frac{\lambda_1}{\max_i|\lambda_i|}x_1,\frac{\lambda_2}{\max_i|\lambda_i|} x_2,..., \frac{\lambda_n}{\max_i|\lambda_i|} x_n)||}{||(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)||}$$
I don't know how to check it. Could you help me?

what about Frobenius norm of the Identity matrix?

Yes. It gives different answer.

this means. this statement is false. right? @Exodd
